# How can I create responsive joystick-layout buttons in HTML?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm creating Raspberry Pi WiFi controlled webcam robot. I've created a responsive window for the webcam feed, but I am unable to create the joystick buttons to control my robot.

This is the type of joystick I want to display below the feed:

[image: Joystick to be displayed below feed]

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

One possibility would be to use SVG:

- It is a scalable vector image format (SVG stands for Scalable Vector Graphic), so it will adapt to different sizes without pixelizing or getting blurry.
- SVG elements support interactivity and animations: so you could have click event listeners in the arrows and center button.
- It is supported by all modern browsers (desktop and mobile).

Here is a demo with a controller similar to the one you have. Click on the "Full page" button to see how it grows and adapts to the width of the parent (20% of the screen) scaling without issues and keeping all the hot spots:

```html
<div id="joystick" style="width:20%">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(16,16,16);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(240,240,240);stop-opacity:1" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(240,240,240);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(16,16,16);stop-opacity:1" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="grad3" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(168,168,168);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(239,239,239);stop-opacity:1" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#grad1)" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47" fill="url(#grad2)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.5px" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="44" fill="url(#grad3)" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="#cccccc" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px" onclick="alert('CENTER');" />
    <path d="M50,14 54,22 46,22Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)" onclick="alert('UP');" />
    <path d="M50,86 54,78 46,78Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)" onclick="alert('DOWN');" />
    <path d="M14,50 22,54 22,46Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)" onclick="alert('LEFT');" />
    <path d="M86,50 78,54 78,46Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)" onclick="alert('RIGHT');" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image map for your joystick buttons. In image map you can use image as a buttons, you need to define coordinates of the images to make it clickable. You can take reference from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp . To make it responsive you can use Media Query. For reference go through http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp